# Loop inside query

Tags: loop, query

I have an array to store taxonomy and term for query, but I can not use foreach to loop my array inside my tax_query. I got 505 internal.

```
    $query = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $query['tax_query'] = array(
         'relation' => 'OR',

        foreach($taxonomy_arr as $t):
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $t[taxonomy],
                'terms' => $t[value],
                'field' => 'slug',
            ),
        endforeach;
    );
```

the foreach or the query works fine on its own but does not work when I loop inside. Please give me advice. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a PHP syntax error - you can't nest a `foreach` *inside* an array, you use it to *build* the array:

```
$query = [
    'post_type'      => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
    ],
];

foreach ( $taxonomy_arr as $t ) {
    $query['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => $t['taxonomy'],
        'terms'    => $t['value'],
        'field'    => 'slug',
    ];
}
```